# React.js: posts.map is not a function

Tags: reactjs

I'm getting this error when running my app and i don't know why!

i have this react component that's getting data from a djagno api that's consists of a title, body for the post, slug, image, date (day and month) and a category.

i have defined posts as an array but it's still giving me an error that's posts.map is not a function.

edit:i found out that the problem maybe cuz the data i'm getting from the api (res.data) which i console logged is an object that has the arrys i want to render

i hope someone can help me with this on cuz i have spent 3 days trying to figure out what's wrong with this code

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom'

const Post = () => {
  const [posts, setPost] = useState([]);



  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchPost = async () => {
      try {
        const res = await axios.get(`${process.env.REACT_APP_API_URL}/api/post/`);
        setPost(res.data);
        console.log('data', res.data);

      }
      catch (err) {

      }
    }

    fetchPost();
  }, []);

  const capitalizeFirstLetter = (word) => {
    if (word)
      return word.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + word.slice(1);
    return '';
  };

  const getPost = () => {
    let list = [];
    let result = [];

    posts.map(blogPost => {
      return list.push(
        <div className="row no-gutters border rounded overflow-hidden flex-md-row mb-4 shadow-sm h-md-250 position-relative">
          <div className="col p-4 d-flex flex-column position-static">
            <strong className="d-inline-block mb-2 text-primary">{capitalizeFirstLetter(blogPost.komite)}</strong>
            <h3 className="mb-0">{blogPost.overskrift}</h3>
            <div className="mb-1 text-muted">{blogPost.måned} {blogPost.dag}</div>
            <Link to={`/post/${blogPost.slug}`} className="stretched-link">Les mer...</Link>
          </div>
          <div className="col-auto d-none d-lg-block">
            <img width='200' height='250' src={blogPost.bilde} alt='bilde' />
          </div>
        </div>
      );
    });

    for (let i = 0; i < list.length; i += 2) {
      result.push(
        <div key={i} className='row mb-2'>
          <div className='col-md-6'>
            {list[i]}
          </div>
          <div className='col-md-6'>
            {list[i+1] ? list[i+1] : null}
          </div>
        </div>
      )
    }

    return result;
  };

  return (

    <div className='container mt-3'>
      <div className="nav-scroller py-1 mb-2">
        <nav className="nav d-flex justify-content-between">
          <Link className="p-2 text-muted" to='/komite/aktulet'>Aktulet</Link>
          <Link className="p-2 text-muted" to='/komite/upop'>Upop</Link>
          <Link className="p-2 text-muted" to='/komite/musikk'>Musikk</Link>
          <Link className="p-2 text-muted" to='/komite/fest'>Fest</Link>
          <Link className="p-2 text-muted" to='/komite/kultur'>Kultur</Link>
          <Link className="p-2 text-muted" to='/komite/debatt'>Debatt</Link>
          <Link className="p-2 text-muted" to='/komite/okonomi'>Økonomi</Link>
          <Link className="p-2 text-muted" to='/komite/pr'>PR</Link>
        </nav>
      </div>



      {getPost()}
    </div>
  );


};

export default Post;
```

Comment: what does `console.log(res.data)` print?

Comment: The api data! i made a couple of posts in the backend to test and console log them just to see if i'm getting the data from the api and it works just fine! the problem is to with rendering them out correctly

Comment: I asked because `res.data` is not an array. your initial set for `posts` is an `[]`, which is an array and has map. The only way to trigger that error is when you update `posts` for another entity, most likely an object. so when you do `setPost(res.data)`, `posts` will be no longer an array.

Comment: yes u r actully right! i used `console.log(typeof res.data);` and i got that's the data is an object!! any idea how to fix that!! I realy appreciate ur help bro

Comment: you could add to the question `res.data` value in order to discover how to retrieve `posts` correctly from res.data

Comment: @buzatto thnak u for ur help! the problem was that i am getting an object of the arrays and i got help in comment bellow that i should access them with `setPost(res.data.results)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't have a chance to test, but I think you may be getting this because there is no guarantee that the posts state has data when the rendering happens. You are calling the API but the rendering happens before the data is available.
One suggestion for loading data from an API like this is to use a loading/isLoaded state as well, and render conditionally to avoid these errors:

```
const [isLoaded, setIsLoaded] = useState(false);
```

And then when you get the data from the API:

```
setIsLoaded(true);
```

Finally, in your rendering code:

```
if ( isLoaded ) {
   return ...
} else {
   return null
}
```

Comment: tried that and it didn't work but i might have misused them cuz i'm a backend developer and pretty new to the frontend side

Comment: It would be helpful to know the format of the data you're getting from the server. I've just tested this with hardcoded data with a timeout. Can you try initializing your state with `useState([{ }])`?

Comment: i console loged the data `console.log(typeof res.data);` i got that's an object!! i think this is the problem it's not an array!! do u have an idea how to fix that!

Comment: Could you paste the results of `console.log(JSON.stringify(res.data))`? Just interested in the structure, feel free to obfuscate the actual results you get.

Comment: i got these!! it's the data from the backend they are 3 posts but i deleted the last 2 cuz it was too long {"count":3,"next":null,"previous":null,"results":[{"id":3,"slug":"overskift-test-1","overskrift":"overskift test","postTekst":"<p>opeariughaoeirgheroaIGHNAEROG RGPOUIEARBGPUOR ERHGPOQHERGIPO</p>","komite":"Debatt","bilde":null,"is_published":true,"dag":"01","måned":"FEB","list_date":"2021-02-01T16:20:10Z","user":2},

Comment: As @buzzato suggested in the comments above this may be better formatted in the original question :) However, if that's res.data, it looks like you want to do `setPost(res.data.results)`, where the array is

Comment: it worked!!!! `setPost(res.data.results)` was the solution. I love u bro <3

Comment: Awesome! Happy to help :) If you can please mark the question as answered it'll help others with similar problems and so other contributors know it is solved.

Answer (score 0):

`posts` should be accessed from `setPost`, which is what you're declaring in your hook.
You're currently calling it from `getPost`, which shouldn't be able to access `posts`.

I might be wrong as I'm new to hooks, but I think that's why it's not working.

Comment: mb u r right! but do u have any idea how to do that??